# if condition is intended to be fulfilled for observation but for value of another variable

Tags: stata

At the moment my code reads: `gen lateFirms = 1 if firmage0 != .`

So at the moment the dataset which I get looks like this:

```
 firm_id  lateFirms firmage0
 1      
 1      
 1      
 1      
 1      
 3      
 3      
 3      
 3      
 3      
 4      
 4      
 4      
 4      
 4      
 5      
 5      
 6  1   110
 6      
 6      
 6      
 6      
 7      
 7      
 7      
 7      
 7      
 8  1   90
 8      
 8      
 8      
 8
```

But what I want is this:

```
 firm_id  lateFirms firmage0
 1      
 1      
 1      
 1      
 1      
 3      
 3      
 3      
 3      
 3      
 4      
 4      
 4      
 4      
 4      
 5      
 5      
 6  1   110
 6  1   
 6  1   
 6  1   
 6  1   
 7      
 7      
 7      
 7      
 7      
 8  1   90
 8  1   
 8  1   
 8  1   
 8  1
```

**NOTE: All blank entries are missing values!**

So "`lateFirms`" should equal 1 if, regarding a "`firm_id`", there exists one observation for which `firmage0` is not a missing value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 bysort firm_id : egen present = count(firmage0)
 replace lateFirms = present > 0
```

The `count()` function of `egen` counts non-missings and assigns the count to all values for each firm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
bysort firm_id: gen dum = 1 if sum(firmage0) != 0
```

To get exactly what you want, you can use `replace` instead of `generate`:

```
bysort firm_id: replace lateFirms = 1 if sum(firmage0) != 0
```

As @NickCox pointed out, this solution is specific to the example dataset you provided.

Comment: Not quite general enough. If the first few values of `firmage0` are missing, the corresponding sum will be 0. If all values are non-missing but 0, then the sum will never rise above 0.